# Nginx subdirectory 404

Tags: nginx, centos

Hey i want install a forum (xenforo) , i already got all the .php files , i put the folder on /usr/share/nginx/html where is the page (main page index.html) , but when i do 127.0.0.1/forum/ i get that error

```
403 Forbidden
nginx/1.10.3
```

so I want to know how can I fix it, the configuration is that one

```
server {
listen       80 default_server;
listen       [::]:80 default_server;
server_name  _;
root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

# Load configuration files for the default server block.
include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

location / {
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
}
```

getenforce is disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you setup Xenforo 2 on nginx you need to read the [documentation here](https://xenforo.com/xf2-docs/manual/options/).

It tells you how to setup the nginx config like this:

```
location /xf/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /xf/index.php?$uri&$args;
    index index.php index.html;
}

location /xf/install/data/ {
    internal;
}
location /xf/install/templates/ {
    internal;
}
location /xf/internal_data/ {
    internal;
}
location /xf/library/ { #legacy
    internal;
}
location /xf/src/ {
    internal;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php?$uri&$args;
    #try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include         fastcgi_params;
}
```

This should fix your issues.  That is what I'm using on centminmod and it works great.  If your forum is located in the root directory remove the "/xf" from each path or if you're in a different folder, change it.